# How to create EntityManager from LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring, jpa, h2, entitymanager

I'm trying to write a JUnit test for a JPA DAO class.

The contructor of the class requires an EntityManager so I am trying to use 
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean to create one.

Once I've created the LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean I'm calling getObject() on it hoping to retrive an EntityManagerFactory to allow me to create the EntityManager, but getObject() returns Null.

I've also tried getNativeEntityManagerFactory(), but it returns Null as well.

What am I doing wrong?

(I'm using H2 as database, but that shouldn't make any difference)

Here's the code:

```
Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "org.h2.Driver");
properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "jdbc:h2:mem:MyUnitTest");

Properties addProperties = new Properties();
addProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
addProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");

LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfCB = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
emfCB.setPersistenceProviderClass(org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.class);
emfCB.setPackagesToScan("com.something.mymodel");
emfCB.setPersistenceUnitName("myUnit");
emfCB.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
//emf.setLoadTimeWeaver(new ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver()); -> This doesn't work
emfCB.setLoadTimeWeaver(new InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver());

JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
emfCB.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
emfCB.setJpaProperties(addProperties);

EntityManagerFactory emf = emfCB.getObject(); // -> This is Null !

MyDao dao = new MyDao(emf);
```

Comment: You should use [spring Junit runner](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.html) for that kind of test (or some mock)

Comment: Take a look at the documentation of Spring Integration Testing from the following link: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing

Comment: Thanks guys, I don't want to use a mock though (well by using H2 I am mocking the database, but I want the code to interact with it as if it was the real DB, not through mockito etc.). @geoand I read the section related to LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean, but there's nothing very useful there and no complete example on how to create an EntityManager.

Comment: If you use the integration testing strategy (and have configured the LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean correctly), you can easily inject the EntityManagerFactory in the test, and from there you can retrieve the EntityManager

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean#afterPropertiesSet](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.html#afterPropertiesSet--) before calling `emfCB.getObject()`, because your `emfCB` should be initialized after all required properties were set, and that before using the bean, this is a part of [the bean lifecycle](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-lifecycle) in Spring.

So your code will be:

```
...
JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
emfCB.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
emfCB.setJpaProperties(addProperties);

emfCB.afterPropertiesSet();
EntityManagerFactory emf = emfCB.getObject(); // -> This won't be Null

MyDao dao = new MyDao(emf);
```